# How to get a contracts emitted events in brownie?

Tags: solidity, events, brownie, logs

Say I have a contract that emits multiple events, how do I to get a list of all events emitted in brownie and sort them by event type?

```
contract SimpleContract {
  
  event Deposit(address indexed _from, bytes32 indexed _id, uint _value);
  event Withdraw(address indexed _to, bytes32 indexed _id, uint _value);

  function deposit(bytes32 _id) external {
    emit Deposit(msg.sender, _id, msg.value);
  }

  function withdraw(bytes32 _id, uint value) external {
    emit Withdraw(msg.sender, _id, value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling a function (creating a transaction) you can check that transactions events with the `events` attribute.

```py
simple_contract = SimpleContract.deploy({"from": account})
tx = simple_contract.deposit(bytes_arg, {"from": account})
print(tx.events)
print(tx.events[0]["Deposit"])
```

Comment: But what if I dont have the tx? what if I just wanna monitor a specific contract for incoming events in general?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being able to access the events of a transaction, one can also use the deployed contract's events attribute.

get_sequence takes a block range and optionally an event type and returns event data from that block range:

```py
    from brownie import SimpleContract, accounts
    from hexbytes import HexBytes
    
    
    def main():
        account = accounts[0]
        contract = SimpleContract.deploy({"from": account})
        contract.deposit(HexBytes(0x0), {"from": account, "value": 10**18})
        events = contract.events.get_sequence(
            from_block=0, to_block=100, event_type="Deposit"
        )
        print(dict(events[0]))
```

Output:

```
{'args': AttributeDict({'_from': '0xEaCB93242793B013Ec51D672bBEF3Ee2b95A081B', '_id': b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', '_value': 1000000000000000000}),
    'event': 'Deposit',
    'logIndex': 0,
    'transactionIndex': 0,
    'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x9d5a21d9011cbbb3978e78c8e9d158237ce4a7a4f3f69acb5bccf44e7345a10b'),
    'address': '0xa0e9a03Bf2243Bbe0f62c851888A9308D722fbEe',
    'blockHash': HexBytes('0xbe36423466db6bf34e73f8ec6eeae076a4197aa36f97b98f1f71ba68d110c38d'),
    'blockNumber': 14}
```

And subscribe lets one pass a callback for when the event fires:

```
   contract.events.subscribe(
        "Withdraw",
        lambda event: print(f"{event['event']} at block {event['blockNumber']}"),
        delay=8,
    )
```

And listen returns a coroutine which resolves to the event object and a timeout bool.

```
   co = contract.events.listen("Withdraw",timeout = 20)
```